# Passing Variable Value to Different Class - Swift

Tags: swift, variables, model-view-controller

I am trying to check the value of two Bool Variables in my view controller. The value is determined in the model. The issue is my view controller keeps seeing the var as false because I initiated it that way rather than value I want it to be which is what the methods in the model are changing it to be.

In my view controller I have:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewdidLoad()    
   self.youWin()
   self.youLose()
}

func youWin () {
     if self.modelInstance.youWon == true  {
      self.gameLetter.text = "You Win!"
        }
    }

func youLose () {
    if self.modelInstance.youLostBool == true {
        self.gameLetter.text = "Game Over!"
    }
}
```

In my model I got

```
var youWonBool = false
var youLoseBools = false 

func time (_ timer: Timer)   {
    if let timeLeft = timer.userInfo as? Timer {
        timeLeft.count -= 1

        timeLeft.callback?(timeLeft.count)
        if self.youWin(secondsLeft: timeLeft.count) == true {
            self.youWonBool = true
        }            
        if timeLeft.count == 0 {
            timer.invalidate()
            self.youLostBool = true
        }
    }
}

func youWin(secondsLeft: Int) -> Bool {
    if self.score >= 90 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

I guess the bigger question here is how do you pass the value of a property from within a method to a different class. Much appreciated!

Comment: Are you calling the time function? In your code the func win/lose it's only called when the viewController loads, so you variables is false. You have to call time func them call win/lose func

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a variable available to the entire class, and set the value of that variable to the value of the variable local to the method. When you reference this code in a different file/class, you can reference the class wide variable.

Comment: do you mind elaborating? I'm not totally sure I see what you're saying. Thank You!